# Set value to bigger variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some homework for my python programming class and I just wanted to know if it was possible to set any variable **c** equal to the greater of **a** and **b** without using an if statement.

**c = bigger(a, b)**

Just a thought since swapping two variables in python is so easy (a, b = b, a) that this might also be.

All help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the built-in `max ()` function - but check your assignment to find out if you're allowed to use it,  sometimes the point of an assignment is to make you implement the feature by yourself.

Comment: It's ok to use it since the main objective is not to do this however the method I chose to solve the problem requires me to do this and I really didn't want to add an if then switch to the code if I didn't need to.

Comment: And thanks for the help